# How to create a Datum for database NULL in PostgreSQL a server side C function?

Tags: postgresql, null, c

I was just wondering how to create a Datum for the database `NULL` value in PostgreSQL?

I known there is `PG_RETURN_NULL()` for *returning* a database NULL in a `LANGUAGE C` function. But I just want to create a Datum for `NULL`, e.g. to be stored in an array (or record). Should I just use `(Datum) 0`?

(This is with PostgreSQL 12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 is a valid value for many data types, so that wouldn't work.

Wherever you have a nullable `Datum` in PostgreSQL server code, you also have a `bool` flag (typically called `isnull`) that indicates if the `Datum` is NULL or not.

Compare the following definition from `src/include/postgres.h`:

```c
/*
 * A NullableDatum is used in places where both a Datum and its nullness needs
 * to be stored. This can be more efficient than storing datums and nullness
 * in separate arrays, due to better spatial locality, even if more space may
 * be wasted due to padding.
 */
typedef struct NullableDatum
{
#define FIELDNO_NULLABLE_DATUM_DATUM 0
    Datum       value;
#define FIELDNO_NULLABLE_DATUM_ISNULL 1
    bool        isnull;
    /* due to alignment padding this could be used for flags for free */
} NullableDatum;
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to return a tuple `(NULL, 1.0)`, how to use `NullableDatum`?

Comment: That depends on the code - how and where exactly do you want to use it? If it is just your own code, and you are not interacting with core code, you can do it however you want. Otherwise the answer depends on where and how you want to use the NULL.

Comment: I think I understand your answer now. I was looking at this line `elem = PG_ARGISNULL(1) ? (Datum) 0 : PG_GETARG_DATUM(1);` in postgres code for array_agg_transfn, and was confused about the `(Datum) 0` part. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That code means: if the first argument `IS NULL`, set `elem` to 0, otherwise set it to the value of the first argument.